# one file 2 different application one to read one to write

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create 2 applications that one always writes to file (like a log file) and other application that can read from a file?

I'd show you what I've tried:

**Writter application**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = @"D:\filetest.txt";
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {

            using(FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(file))
            {
                using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine($"line line {i++}");
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

**reader application**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = @"D:\filetest.txt";
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            string lines = string.Empty;
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                using (StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                     lines = sw.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(lines);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
```

Of course as I expected I got exception on `File.OpenWrite(file)` line 
`"he process cannot access the file 'D:\filetest.txt' because it is being used by another process."`

The only solution I think is to copy the written file before reading it.

Comment: To ensure this isn't a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you take a step back and explain why you need this code?

Comment: as i wrote its writing a log file the reading in this case will allow us to analyse the log file  - i cant do anything in the writer application

Comment: Use File.Open and allowing sharing

Comment: You may need to update the logic in the linked post a bit to not stop when you've reached the end of the file, assuming you want to read things as they're being written.

Comment: @mjwills you provide me better solution the fileshare flag was the diffrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [`File.OpenWrite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) states:

> Return Value Type: System.IO.FileStream An **unshared** FileStream object
>   on the specified path with Write access.

You could consider using a **shared** FileStream:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
```

*`FileShare.Read` will allow `File.OpenRead` to work.*